# Run a Command and then Parameter Substitution in one line

Tags: bash, command-substitution

```
bash# hostname
host1.example.com
```

I only want host1. So:

```
SHORT_HOST=$(/bin/hostname)
SHORT_HOST=${SHORT_HOST%%.*}
```

Can I turn this into a one liner?
 - or -
what is the best way to make $SHORT_HOST readonly, but still get the short hostname?

Answer (score 5):

If you're not limited to just bash's tools, maybe try

```
SHORT_HOST=$(hostname | sed -e 's/\..*//')
```

or

```
SHORT_HOST=$(hostname | cut -d. -f1)
```

Answer (score 4):

If your environment supports this, you could simply:

```
typeset -r SHORT_HOST="$(/bin/hostname -s)"
```

Answer (score 3):

This is just another way using `awk` command:

```
/bin/hostname | awk -F'.' '{print $1}'
```

and if you need to store it in a SHORT_HOST variable use the following:

```
SHORT_HOST=$(/bin/hostname | awk -F'.' '{print $1}')
```

Answer (score 2):

In shells other than zsh, you need to perform an intermediate assignment whenever you want to perform multiple transformations on a value.

Of course, there are sometimes workarounds, such as [running a command that produces the desired result with no postprocessing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23798/run-a-command-and-then-parameter-substitution-in-one-line/23806#23806) or [doing the postprocessing via a pipe](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23798/run-a-command-and-then-parameter-substitution-in-one-line/23810#23810) [through an external tool](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23798/run-a-command-and-then-parameter-substitution-in-one-line/23805#23805) (the pipe solution will be slower and runs into more risk of mangling newlines).

If you want to make the variable read-only, you might find it cleaner to assign to a temporary variable.

```
tmp=$(/bin/hostname)
typeset -r SHORT_HOST="${tmp%%.*}"
```

Zsh (but not ksh or bash) supports nested parameter substitutions. There, you can write

```
typeset -r SHORT_HOST=${$(/bin/hostname)%%.*}
```